# How to create an object with choices/types?

Tags: c#

I want to have an object where I can choose an *answer* type. For example:

```
if (player_answer == answer.true)
...
```

or

```
if (player_answer == answer.noneoftheabove)
...
```

In the past I just use `if (player_answer == "noneoftheabove")` which is a bit inefficient since it's pure hard coded. How can I create that `answer` class/object?

Comment: What sort of data type are you looking for? Do you know about Enums?

Comment: Yeah I guess that's the thing I was looking for - `enums`. Can anyone post an answer so I can close the question? Thank you! :)